# Creating djcelery tables with the presence of South

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-celery

According to django-celery's [documentation](https://github.com/ask/django-celery#installation), if I have South I should call

```
python manage.py migrate djcelery
```

However, all it does is creating some migration file:

```
Running migrations for djcelery:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial
 > djcelery:0001_initial
 - Loading initial data for djcelery.
No fixtures found.
```

It does not create the following tables like it should be doing. I did syncdb after removing south from INSTALLED_APPS:

```
Creating table djcelery_intervalschedule
Creating table djcelery_crontabschedule
Creating table djcelery_periodictasks
Creating table djcelery_periodictask
Creating table djcelery_workerstate
Creating table djcelery_taskstate
```

However, when south is present, these tables are not created with

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Weird thing is, somehow yesterday I was able to get those tables with syncdb, but I honestly don't know what I did to make it work and could not reproduce it. This happens on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10

I am wondering if I am doing it wrong. Any input will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem and were able to get all the tables created with South installed by using the `--all` flag with `syncdb`:

```
python manage.py syncdb --all
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that djcelery fails silently if the tables already exists : see https://github.com/ask/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/migrations/0001_initial.py

You may try to patch the migration and prints the exception message. It may help.

Edit: May be you can try to edit the ignore_exists in 0001_initial.py with the following. (Ok not very clean but it may help to understand)

```
def ignore_exists(fun, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        fun(*args, **kwargs)
    except DatabaseError, exc:
        print "##", exc #This is the patch
        if "exists" in str(exc):
            return False
        raise
    return True
```

Comment: Hi Luc, thanks for the reply! If possible, can you precisely describe what should be the steps to take please? (i.e., patching and printing the exception message.)

Answer (score -1):

Just run this command, I recently use it and created all djcelery tables.

```
python manage.py migrate
```